# Whats wrong with this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals, completing-the-square

$$\int \frac{(x+7)dx}{x^2+2x+5}$$

completing the square we get:

$$(x^2+2x+1)+5-1$$
$$(x+1)^2+4$$
then:
$$U = x + 1$$
$$a = 2$$
hence:

$$\int \frac{(U+6)dU}{U^2+a^2}$$

using trig substitution $U = a\tan\theta$ and $dU = a\sec^2\theta d\theta$:

$$\int a\tan\theta d\theta + 6\int d\theta$$
$$a\ln(\sec\theta) + 6\theta$$
$$a\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2+U^2}}{a}\right) + 6\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{U}{a}\right)$$
$$2\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}{2}\right)+ 6\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right) $$

what did I get wrong?

book answer:

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+2x+5)+ 3\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is here

$$\int \frac{(U+6)dU}{U^2+a^2}=\color{red}{\int a\tan\theta d\theta +  6\int d\theta}$$

we should have

$$\int \frac{(U+6)dU}{U^2+a^2}=\int \tan\theta d\theta + \frac 6a\int d\theta$$

since

$$\frac{dU}{U^2+a^2}=\frac{\frac a{\cos^2 \theta}d\theta}{\frac {a^2}{\cos^2 \theta}}=\frac1ad\theta$$

We obtain indeed

$$\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}{2}\right)+ 3\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)$$

with

$$\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}{2}\right)=\frac12\ln\left(\frac{x^2+2x+5}{4}\right)=\frac12\ln\left(x^2+2x+5\right)+C$$

Comment: what about the missing square root in the book answer?

Comment: what happens to the 4 in the denominator?

Comment: This gives just a constant since $\log \frac A B = \log A - \log B$.

Comment: What did you do in the first step to get rid of the square root?

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts Here we have used that $\log (A^B)=B\log A$.

Comment: why B is 1/2 instead of 2?

Comment: The full step is this $$\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}{2}\right)=\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2x+5}{4}}\right)=\frac12\ln\left(\frac{x^2+2x+5}{4}\right)=\frac12\ln\left(x^2+2x+5\right)-\frac12\log 4$$ whic is in the form $$\log \left(\frac A C\right)^B=B\left(\log A-\log C\right)=B\log A-B\log C$$.

Comment: ohh thanks, I thought you were squaring

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts We just factor out the exponent $\frac12$ and eliminate a constant to obtain the given solution. You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Consider$$\int\frac{U+6}{U^2+4}\,\mathrm dU.$$If you do $U=2\tan\theta$ and $\mathrm dU=2(1+\tan^2\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$, what you do get is$$\int\tan\theta\,\mathrm d\theta+\int3\,\mathrm d\theta.$$Besides,$$\int\tan\theta\,\mathrm d\theta=-\log(\cos\theta).$$

Comment: integral of $\tan\theta$ is $ln(secx)$

Comment: No, it is not.${}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, it is true, however there is a mistake with notation $\theta$ and $x$

Comment: You are right. Sorry about that. Both $\int\tan\theta\,\mathrm d\theta=-\log(\cos\theta)$ and $\int\tan\theta\,\mathrm d\theta=\log(\sec\theta)$ are correct.

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts $\ln(\sec x)$ and $-\ln(\cos x)$ are equivalent due to the properties of the logarithm

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x + 7}{x^{2} + 2x + 5}\mathrm{d}x & = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x + 14}{x^{2} + 2x + 5}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x + 2}{x^{2} + 2x + 5}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{12}{x^{2} + 2x + 5}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}(x^{2} + 2x + 5)}{x^{2} + 2x + 5} + 3\int\frac{\mathrm{d}((x + 1)/2)}{((x + 1)/2)^{2} + 1}\\\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\ln(x^{2} + 2x + 5) + 3\arctan\left(\frac{x + 1}{2}\right) + C
\end{align*}

Comment: Why the downvote?